Cohen's kappa in single-n design with one rater
I'm doing a single-n case study and would like to calculate the consistency of the patient's responses to the same set of questions over two time points (all of which have a 'yes/no' answer format).
Would Cohen's kappa be a valid measure of agreement in this context? Or can is it only suitable when two raters make categorical decisions about the same item?
Either way, I would appreciate knowing why, and if it isnt appropriate, whether there are any alternative ways to quantify agreement in this context.

Can you give an example of what your data look like?

I believe Kappa is for independent raters. You may want an intra-class correlation unless the scale is nominal-categorical.
